# My query is producing incorrect results. Any ideas why?

Tags: sql-server

We have work flow that starts with employee submitting a request.

Upon submitting this request, employee's ID as well as his/her manager's ID, Director's ID and PersonnelManagerID are saved to the database.

There is a field called RequestStatus with three options, Pending, Complete or Cancelled.

By default, RequestStatus is pending.

Once RequestStatus changes to Complete, this request is routed to the manager.

Similarly, once manager's decision is in Complete Status, the request is routed to the Director who does his/her part and routs to Personnel Director for final action.

There are four tables involved here.

Employees table with employeeID, employeeName, EmployeeUsername and employeePassword, among other field names. These are the relevant ones.

There is the DeptHead table.

This table contains DirectorID, DirectorName, among other fields. These are the relevant fields.

Personnel with PersonnelManagerID

Then there is the Request table.

This is the table where requests are submitted and it includes employeeID, managerId, DirectorID and requestStatus.

All Employees including Manager, Director and Personnel Manager are all in Employee's table as empname and Empnum.

Employee ID is saved as empID in Request table
Manager's employee ID is saved as ManagerID in Request table
Directors Employee Id is saved as DirectorId in Request table

Personnel Managers employeeID is saved as PersonneID in Request table

If an employee logs in, his/her ReqeustStatus should either be Pending, Complete or Cancelled.

Right now, when I log in as an employee, RequestStatus is null even though there is no null value on the database.

Any ideas what I need to change on the query below.

```
select 
 IsNull(r.mgrid,'NA') mgrid,
 IsNULL(r.RequestStatus,'NA') AS RequestStatus,
 h.deptname, 
 isNull(p.DirectorName, 'N') DirectorName, 
 IsNull(r.DirectorID,'NA') DirectorID, 
 h.DeptNum deptNumber, 
 E.DeptNum, 
 E.Department, 
 E.EmpName, 
 E.EmpID, 
 E.Password, 
 h.empname as director 
 from Employee e 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN DeptHeads h on e.EmpID = h.directorId 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Personnel p on e.EmpID = p.EmpID 
   LEFT JOIN Request r ON r.managerID = e.EmpID OR r.DirectorID = e.EmpID 
 where e.EmpID = 'myUsername' and e.SSN = 'mypassword' order by e.department asc
```

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Where are you even dealing with RequestStatus  in the query you have provided?

Comment: Log in where? What does that query have to do with it? Is that what is run when you "log in"? It doesn't actually have a field called request status in it. Surely there are may requests per employee so are all of them NULL or just some?

Comment: I suppose you've submitted not all code. There is no field named RequestStatus, `a.DirectorID = e.EmpID` but there is no table aliased with 'a'.

Comment: finishedorunfinished is not know to what table it belongs... It doesn't have the alias to the table that belongs to

Comment: Sorry helpers.

I was trying to mask the query so as to not get in trouble. As a result, I left some stuff out. 

Please see corrected query.

@Nick.McDermaid, to answer your great question, the only field I am getting NULL values for is the RequestStatus.

The query Nick, takes the employee to his or her appropriate page based on his or her log in credentials.

Comment: When you run that query there is no way you can get a NULL for the column `RequestStatus` so the issue must be in your application.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, I am sorry but you are wrong.

Yes, I am using it in my .net application but I have run this code several times on SSMS and the only difference is that if I run it using manager, director or Personnel ID, it works in that a value is assigned to RequestStatus.

If I run it using regular employee ID, RequestStatus has the value of NA and that's because of the Isnull(...). Otherwise, it will show null.

Comment: The expression `IsNULL(r.RequestStatus,'NA')` will never return NULL. Perhaps the problem is that the `where` clause is false (due to incorrect password maybe), and the query returns no rows so you're application shows 'NULL'. That query alone will not produce that behaviour unless someone actually put the actual string 'NULL' in that field.

Comment: I'm not saying you're not seeing it, I'm just saying you need to explain more for us to understand what you're seeing. If you're seeing this in the application perhaps you could post the application code.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, Am I not explaining myself well?

I said earlier that the query returns NULL when I log in as an employee.

The only reason you NA is because I am using isnull.

Second, I said I have tried testing the query itself in sql server management studio (SSMS). I also said I am using the correct password.

I also said it returns correct value when I log in as manager, director and personnel. It is only when I log in as employee that requeststatus returns null.
Finally, the problem seems to be with the left join, not left outer join but left join.

Comment: a left join _is_ a left outer join. Are you saying 1. When you log into your _application_ as an employee, the _RequestStatus_ field in your application returns NULL? or are you saying when you log into _SSMS_ and use parameters that look like an employee the expression _IsNULL(r.RequestStatus,'NA')_ returns NULL? I'm sorry if I sound pedantic but your explanations are ambiguous (I'm not attacking you just trying to understand).

Comment: If your left join doesn't match a `Request` record, `RequestStatus` will be NULL and ISNULL will turn it to NA. Is that what is happening?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, when I tried testing my application to see what happens if I log in as an employee or manager or director or personnel. I discovered that if I log in as employee, I get results alright but requestStatus is always null even though there is no null values on the database for RequestStatus.

So, to make sure that my application is not the issue, I copied the query into ssms to test it there. It became obvious then that my query is the issue.

Essentially, if requeststatus is pending, do one thing. If complete, then something else. IF cancelled, do something else. Nothing will...

Comment: No of those conditions will work for an employee because requestStatus is always null for an employee.

Like I said, the problem is with this predicate:

`LEFT JOIN Request r ON r.managerID = e.EmpID OR r.DirectorID = e.EmpID`

If I change the left join to inner join, it works for employees but not for some personnel folks. So, that line is the issue. I just don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: Are you saying you run that exact query in SSMS and you substitute in a  valid `EmpID` and `SSN`, you see a resultset with the word NULL in the column `RequestStatus`. How many rows do you see? are there any otgher NULL's? Because I know that if you run `SELECT ISNULL(NULL,'NA')` all on it's own it will not return NULL, it will return 'NA'. I'm sure if I could see your screen we could have this done in a jiffy.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, 

Any database developer knows what isnull() does. What I am saying (once again) is that if I use ANY valid regular employee ID to log in, RequstStatus value is null. So, I replace that null with NA but this is not even relevant.

What is relevant is that there is something wrong with the last Left join query because when I test with ManagerID, or DirectorID, or PersonnelID, requestStatus is either Pending, Completed, or Cancelled. Those are three possible values.

The fact that requeststatus returns null for regular employees means something is wrong with the query.

Comment: When you say "requeststatus returns null for regular employees" do you mean it returns NULL _before_ it goes into the ISNULL function? If you can provide sample data, current output and required output then maybe I can help. It seems like simply there are no matching Request for employees. Which is a function of your data. You don't have sample data so I really don't know.